# How to align divs with input elements of a form?

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align 3 divs (that will contain icons) with input fields of a form. Is there any explanation why are form elements acting like they have top margins even after i set it to 0?

```
<form>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password">
</form>
```

---

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
form {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnW4C/1/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add `vertical-align:top` to the elements in order to solve the alignment issues.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UQsL8/)

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background: red;
    vertical-align:top;  /* It works because they are inline-block.. */
}
```

Alternatively, the values `middle` and `bottom` would work too. It just needs to be something other than the default value, which is `baseline`.

If you're wondering *why* the value `baseline` was behaving as it was, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278).

Comment: how does changing the vertical position of the `<div>` move the input up and down? O_o

Comment: I was using central, didn't remember middle...
It works with middle, thank you very much man!

Comment: @Phil *That*, I can't explain. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278) is relevant though.